# Deleting an unlocked file in C#

Tags: c#, file, delete-file

In a C# program, I am creating files. I want to delete one file using this command:-

```
File.Delete(killFile);
```

The killFile has a value = `"C:\Documents and Settings\MehdiAnis\My Documents\outfile_0020.csv"`
The killFile is an existing file.

After I run Delete command, file is still in the Directory. Right after delete I added FileInfo code to check if the file exists,

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(killFile);
```

Now, fi.Exists shows false

I am not sure what's wrong, can it be permission issue? I just wrote the file in my own folder, why can't I delete it? Once the file is created I am not opening it or doing anything with it, so it should not be locked.

What could be wrong and where else should I be looking?

Comment: If you put a try...catch around this command, catch all exceptions, what do you see?

Comment: just an idea: Are you on a Windows7 system?

Comment: I've seen this before in my own code, problem is I don't remember the exact solution. It was either something with UAC (run the application as an admin) or permission on the file / folder. I'll add another comment when I get a chance to look into it tomorrow.

Comment: If you're using Windows Vista or Windows 7, "My Documents" isn't at that location, but rather it's (usually) at `c:\users\<username>\My Documents`. You can use `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` to get the actual path you need, regardless of OS.

Comment: Yas4891 & dlev :: No, it's Windows 2003 Server, a terminal server, I remote in to code in it. I can delete the same file right-click->delete, or from command prompt - just not from the code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the screenshot you posted at  http://i548.photobucket.com/albums/ii341/MehdiAnis/cprob.jpg

In your screen shot, the explorer window is showing a file with name eding in "_0020.csv" . You are passing in a filename ending with "_20.csv", according to the debugger window.  You are calling File.Delete with the name of a file that doesn't actually exist, and so no file is deleted.

You will want to format your "killFile" variable with 0 padding.  I assume you are adding some counter to it like `killfile = killFile + i.ToString()`.   Try `killfile = killFile + i.ToString("0000")`

Comment: I think that if you call `File.Delete` on file that doesn't exists it will throw exception.

Comment: No it does not. See the remarks section of the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) "If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown."

Comment: @Scott: Yes you are right, I tested it now and found out that it doesn't throw exception if file doesn't exists..

Comment: Indeed! I used string.Format("{0:d4}", fileCount) to create the file, but when assigned value to killFile used just fileCOunt, thus '0020' != '20'.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx), "If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown."

You may want to check for existence of the file to be deleted using File.Exists **before** trying to delete it.  I think your problem is the file you are expecting to delete isn't the file that you see in the folder.